# sql float precision issue

Tags: sql, apache-spark, precision

I have a table fruit_df_sql like this

```
     +------+------------+
     | fruit|fruit_number|
     +------+------------+
     | apple|          20|
     |orange|          33|
     |  pear|          27|
     | melon|          31|
     |  plum|           8|
     |banana|           4|
     +------+------------+
```

I want to generate the percentage of each row but when I sum up the percentage column I could not get 100%

```
    select fruit, round(fruit_number/123*100,2) as cnt_percent 
    from fruit_df_sql
    order by cnt_percent desc
```

If I sum  the column of cnt_percent I got this

```
    +----------------+
    |sum(cnt_percent)|
    +----------------+
    |           99.99|
    +----------------+
```

not 100%. I think it is because the division  and round  bring in float precision issue. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This happens with percents.  It's not particularly easy to fix.

Comment: its fine for me, what is your fruit_number datatype?? i think it must be float.

Comment: it is int or long

Comment: sometime it might be 100.01, it is very annoying

Comment: What is the DBMS?

Comment: it's inside Spark.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, `round` will "transform" number, so you cant expect to find the same sum at the end.

Answer (score -1):

*Try* rounding it off to 0 decimals.

```
select fruit, round(fruit_number/123*100,0) as cnt_percent 
from fruit_df_sql
order by cnt_percent desc;
```

Comment: I have to keep at least 2 decimals.

Comment: Does your system requires a float value? if not, you could change the type of your field into `decimal(10,2)` - 10 meaning the precision and 2 for decimal places.

Comment: So my input  fruit_number is integer, bigint, my output is percentage  and I need to keep 2 decimals like 9.70%,  0.10%,0.01%

Comment: Try using `float` datatype in your `fruit_number`. It handles precision more. Int is used for numbers without decimals points.